# React Native with Redux - Unexpected token

Tags: reactjs, react-native, react-redux, react-native-ios

I've started working with React-Native and run iOS.
I'm creating an app based on f8App that is shared in github, but upgrading to the latest dependencies.

I'm also using Redux in order to run this app. The initial goal in this case is to load the Login page which will use firebase Auth.

Below is the `setup.js`:

```
/**
 * @flow
 */

'use strict';

import React, { Component } from 'React';
import {Provider} from 'react-redux';
import AsistenciaApp from './AsistenciaApp';
import {configureStore} from './store/configureStore';

function setup(): ReactClass<{}> {
    class Root extends Component {
        state: {
            isLoading: boolean;
            store: any;
        };

        constructor() {
            super();
            this.state = {
                isLoading = true,
                store:
                    configureStore(
                        () => this.setState({isLoading: false})
                    )
            };
        }

        render() {
            if (this.state.isLoading) {
                return null;
            }

            return (
                <Provider store={this.state.store}>
                    <AsistenciaApp />
                </Provider>
            );
        };
    }

    return Root;
}

module.exports setup;
```

When I run `react-native run-ios`, I get the following error:

`Syntax Error setup.js Unexpected token, expected, (25,30)`

Which points to this function `configureStore`, below I attach the code for that file:

```
/**
 *
 * @flow
 */

 'use strict';

 import {applyMiddleware, createStore} from 'redux';
 import thunk from 'redux-thunk';
 import promise from './promise';
 import array from './array';
 import {createLogger} from 'redux-logger';
 import reducers from '../reducers';
 import {persistStore, autoRehydrate} from 'redux-persist';
 import {AsyncStorage} from 'react-native';


 let isDebuggingInChrome = __DEV__ && !!window.navigator.userAgent;

 let logger = createLogger({
   predicate: (getState, action) => isDebuggingInChrome,
   collapsed: true,
   duration: true,
 });

let createD4mStore = applyMiddleware(thunk, promise, array, logger)(createStore);

function configureStore(onComplete: ?() => void) {
    const store = autoRehydrate()(createD4mStore)(reducers);
    persistStore(store, {storage: AsyncStorage}, onComplete);
    if (isDebuggingInChrome) {
         window.store = store;
    }

    return store;
}

module.exports = configureStore;
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have `configureStore` exported as `default`. Replace:

```js
import {configureStore} from './store/configureStore';
```

with

```js
import configureStore from './store/configureStore';
```

Or export `configureStore` as named `export`. Replace:

```js
module.exports = configureStore;
```

with

```js
export configureStore;
```